# how to match a particular pattern using regex?

Tags: python, regex, django

I am using django and in `urls.py` there is a regex pattern:

```
url(r'^note/(\d+)/$', 'publicnote'),
url(r'^note/$', 'publicnote'),
```

this works fine. But i decided to add a name to url. so i redesigned the regex:

```
url(r'^note/(\d*)/?$', 'publicnote',name='public_note'),
```

but the problem is this will match `note//`.

so is there any regex so that it will match only `note/` and `note/<an integer>/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regexp should work:

```
r'^note/(?:(\d+)/)?$'
```

The `?` makes the previous group optional.

Comment: could you please explain `?:`

Comment: It makes the group non-capturing. The parentheses are only needed to provide a group for the `?` to operate on.

Comment: thanks. for `33/` regex pattern `((\d+)/)?` matches `33/,33`, and for `33/` regex pattern `(?:(\d+)/)?` matches just `33`